# Change sticky footer according to changing viewport when opening soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an onboarding process for an app, and part of that is the following screen:

[image]

This is no problem. When the user taps the input field and the keyboard opens, this is what *should* happen:

[image]

I know the screens have seperate content but I'm sure you'll get the idea. On the first screen, the footer is made sticky to the bottom using this structure: [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

A simplified example of my code:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
 I'm signed up with
<input type="text" />
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
 <a href="#">Next</a>
</footer>
```

So what needs to happen is that the sticky footer comes up along with the keyboard. The problem is however, that on iOS (I'm not sure about Android), the viewport does not change at all. The keyboard is just an overlay, with a slight animation to move the input field to the center of the visible screen. So this won't actually work, the "Next" button is now out of sightx.

As far as I know, there is *no* way to access the remaining viewport using JS. Ideally I would have that to animate the footer.

So I guess the only thing left to do is hardcode the pixels for each and every device out there and then go from there when the input is selected  / deselected. Which obviously is impossible to do and to maintain.

So my question is this: **is** there actually a way to do this rather clean whilst covering most of the popular devices? If so, how, and if not, what are the other options (if any)?

Thanks!

Comment: This might not be what you want to hear, but mobile design best practice generally dictates that a sticky footer should disappear when the mobile keyboard appears. The remaining screen real estate is so small after opening the keyboard that a sticky footer would basically obscure almost all of the remaining browser viewport.